# Compute Matrix with Respect to Basis:

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, self-learning

I have an exam tomorrow and trying to understand this question:

Let $f(x,y)=(xy,y/x)$ compute $Df$. Compute the matrix of $Df(x,y)$ with respect to basis $(1,0),(1,1) $ in $ R^2$

First I found the matrix $Df = \begin{bmatrix}y & x\\-y/x^2 & 1/x\end{bmatrix}.$

Not sure what the next step is - I thought maybe:

$\begin{bmatrix}y & x\\-y/x^2 & 1/x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}y \\-y/x^2 \end{bmatrix}  $

$\begin{bmatrix}y & x\\-y/x^2 & 1/x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}y+x \\-y/x^2 + 1/x\end{bmatrix}  $

So the final answer: 
$\begin{bmatrix}y & y+x\\-y/x^2 & -y/x^2 + 1/x\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: Your initial matrix goes from canonical to canonical. The second one goes from new basis to canonical. You still have to multiply on the left by the inverse to go from canonical to new basis.

Comment: Once you have got the matrix, your problem is only linear algebra. You should looking for some questions about changing basis in this forum.